# Hibernate generates error when inserting two objects of a many2one at the same time

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm using postgreql (If matters) and I have two classes with this mappings:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.mydomain.models.TokenizedForm" table="TOKENIZEDFORM">
 <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
  <column name="ID" sql-type="INTEGER"/>
  <generator class="increment"/>
 </id>
 <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="name" type="java.lang.String">
  <column length="255" name="NAME" sql-type="VARCHAR"/>
 </property>
 <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="body" type="java.lang.String">
  <column length="9999999" name="BODY" sql-type="VARCHAR"/>
 </property>
 <set lazy="true" name="tokens" sort="unsorted" table="FORMTOKENS">
  <key>
   <column name="ID" sql-type="INTEGER"/>
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="com.mydomain.models.FormTokens"/>
 </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Oct 7, 2013 10:31:46 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="com.mydomain.models.FormTokens" table="FORMTOKENS">
  <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
   <column name="ID" sql-type="INTEGER"/>
   <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>
  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="text" type="java.lang.String">
   <column length="1023" name="TEXT" sql-type="VARCHAR"/>
  </property>
  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="delimiter" type="java.lang.String">
   <column length="255" name="DELIMITER" sql-type="VARCHAR"/>
  </property>
  <many-to-one class="com.mydomain.models.TokenizedForm"
   fetch="join" name="form">
   <column name="FORM" sql-type="INTEGER"/>
  </many-to-one>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now when running this code:

```
Session session = getSession();
Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();

TokenizedForm form = new TokenizedForm("my fm", "body of it here");
session.save(form);

FormTokens ft0 = new FormTokens("my token 1", "[[]]");
ft0.setForm(form);

FormTokens ft1 = new FormTokens("my t1", "<<>>");
ft1.setForm(form);

session.save(ft0);
session.save(ft1);

transaction.commit();
```

I get the following:

```
Hello World!
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Hibernate: select max(ID) from TOKENIZEDFORM
Hibernate: select max(ID) from FORMTOKENS
Hibernate: insert into TOKENIZEDFORM (NAME, BODY, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into FORMTOKENS (TEXT, DELIMITER, FORM, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into FORMTOKENS (TEXT, DELIMITER, FORM, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:58)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3067)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3509)
  at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:286)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
  at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
  at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
  at com.mydomain.App.d(App.java:55)
  at com.mydomain.App.main(App.java:22)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "formtokens" violates foreign key constraint "fk_37kmr0diunms0vx0boagmc43f"
  Detail: Key (id)=(3) is not present in table "tokenizedform".
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
  ... 15 more
```

Where 3 is the ID of FormToken. Not a TokenizedForm in database. (tf0 and tf1 id's are 2 and 3 because I have already inserted a row with ID 1 to database).
If I try to add only one FormToken **it works in each run**! This problem happens with two or more instances of FormTokens added during one run. I could add zillion billions of FormTokens by adding only one instance of FormTokens during each run.
I tried removing any trace of FormTokens from TokenizedForm but  (removing set from mapping and...) but doesn't make any difference, I even tried to commit and begin a new transaction after one FormToken insert. I tries closing and opening a new session too! But same thing happens over and over.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try form.getTokens().add(ft0) and 
form.getTokens().add(ft1) and session.saveOrUpdate(form)

Comment: also, can you provide the tables structure with FK and PK details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-bidirectional-m21) for how to map a bidirectional one-to-meny association. Your mapping is wrong, since it tells, in

```
<set lazy="true" name="tokens" sort="unsorted" table="FORMTOKENS">
  <key>
   <column name="ID" sql-type="INTEGER"/>
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="com.mydomain.models.FormTokens"/>
</set>
```

that the ID column in formtokens is used to refer to the primary key of the tokenizedforms table. It should be

```
<set lazy="true" name="tokens" sort="unsorted" table="FORMTOKENS">
  <key>
   <column name="FORM" sql-type="INTEGER"/>
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="com.mydomain.models.FormTokens"/>
</set>
```

instead. Of course, make sure to regenerate the database schema from scratch it you let Hibernate generate it for you, because it probably generated a FK constraint that wasn't removed when you tried to remove this set completely.